# Wordpress - Show Same Text on Every Page of a WordPress Site

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to implement my custom HTML5/CSS template into Wordpress from scratch. However, I don't find a function how I can create a content that will remain same on all pages. Till now whatever I tried to do made me realize that I need to create it separately for each page. To be more clear on what I want to achieve please have a look at my site's header's screenshot below:

Header Screenhot

[image]

Footer Screenshot

[image]

Here you can see I have texts like phone number, email on top and footer also has static texts like the title of each column `Products`, `Quick Links`, `Contact Us`. I can keep this static but I want to give the user the flexibility to change these texts if they want too from their wordpress dashboard. I want to create this once so that it remains same on all the pages dynamically. How can I do this? Which wordpress function should I use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a new/custom widget area and add a text block to that new widget area.
Instructions can be found here: https://buckleupstudios.com/add-a-new-widget-area-to-a-wordpress-theme/

Comment: Thanks! The code there to display the widgets displays all the text widgets that I created. Is there a way to call each one separately like `$widget['callText']` or `$widget->callText` something like that to call a specific widget?

Comment: Yes, all of the widgets you "drop in" will be visible. There's a plugin called "Widget Logic" that can display widgets based on conditions, if that's what you're after.

Comment: hmm.. I found another way though :)